# can‘t install kobuki

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello， everybody

I am New-hand in ROS，

I wnat to install TurtleBot to study，

but I meet the problem：

```
[  4%] Built target unflasher
Scanning dependencies of target kobuki_dock_drive
[  4%] Building CXX object kobuki_core/kobuki_dock_drive/CMakeFiles/kobuki_dock_drive.dir/src/dock_drive.cpp.o
In file included from /home/tonywang/kobuki/src/kobuki_core/kobuki_dock_drive/src/dock_drive.cpp:38:0:
/home/tonywang/kobuki/src/kobuki_core/kobuki_dock_drive/include/kobuki_dock_drive/dock_drive.hpp:51:42: fatal error: ecl/geometry/legacy_pose2d.hpp: 沒有此一檔案或目錄
 #include <ecl/geometry/legacy_pose2d.hpp>
                                          ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [kobuki_core/kobuki_dock_drive/CMakeFiles/kobuki_dock_drive.dir/src/dock_drive.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [kobuki_core/kobuki_dock_drive/CMakeFiles/kobuki_dock_drive.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

[image: image description]

I have above problem when I install kobuki，

Could everybody teach me how could I solve it？

thanks！

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244937/can%E2%80%98t-install-kobuki/) by [saver54012](https://answers.ros.org/users/28147/saver54012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-10-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-04**:
First: please tell us why you want to build the `kobuki` packages from source. They have been released into Hydro, Indigo and Kinetic, so an `apt-get install ros-indigo-kobuki-core` should just work.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-04**:
Second, apparently `沒有此一檔案或目錄` means "no such file or directory": do you have `ecl` installed? Please tell us which OS this is, how you installed ROS (which tutorial you followed) and how you setup your workspace (`git clone ..`, `rosdep`, etc).

**Comment by [saver54012](https://answers.ros.org/users/28147/saver54012/) on 2016-10-04**:
thank gvdhoorn for answering!!
I just followed this tutorial "http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo"，I have the troble at Step 2.1，I cant complete "1.3.2 Workspaces" because $catkin_make in ~/kobuki is failed

I have "ecl" file by git clone ,but I dont know it should be installed at where

**Comment by [saver54012](https://answers.ros.org/users/28147/saver54012/) on 2016-10-04**:
I installed my ROS Indigo from http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-05**:
re: turtlebot installation: have you run all the `rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y`? Did those not install `ecl`?

**Comment by [Nick Hoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28099/nick-hoo/) on 2016-10-07**:
I meet the same problem.And I do not know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ecl and kobuki both got a minor (synchronised) update that are still in the release pipeline. The problem you have here is you have the as yet unreleased kobuki sources, but have the old released ecl deb.

To solve it for now, just add ecl_core to your kobuki workspace...i.e.

```
cd ~/kobuki/src
wstool set ecl_core --git https://github.com/stonier/ecl_core --version=release/0.61-indigo-kinetic
wstool set ecl_navigation --git https://github.com/stonier/ecl_navigation --version=release/0.60-indigo-kinetic
wstool update ecl_core
wstool update ecl_navigation
```

This will be resolved by:

- ecl_core 0.61.15, ecl_navigation 0.60.3, kobuki_core 0.6.5 and kobuki 0.6.8 on kinetic
- ecl_core 0.61.15, ecl_navigation 0.60.3, kobuki_core 0.7.2 and kobuki 0.7.2 on kinetic

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2016-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [glukon](https://answers.ros.org/users/31987/glukon/) on 2017-10-24**:
I had the same problem on a Jetson TK1 (Linux4Tegra -> Ubuntu 14.04) with ros-indigo. Here the kobuki_node is located in `~/catkin_ws/src/`. Your soultion is nice but first I needed to `wstool init ~/catkin_ws/src`, then run wstool set and update commands. So make sure to have wstool init first :-)